# Advantage of Digital Elevation Model (DEM) in Agriculture?

Tags: dem, agriculture

I have given the task to create Digital Elevation Model (DEM)'s of an agricultural area. I am programmer with Computer Science background and very new to GIS can anyone explain what is advantage of using Digital Elevation Model (DEM) in agriculture ?

Comment: According to me your question is huge.Please go through following research paper http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/etd/11017/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some uses of DEM in agriculture, that were not cited yet:

1- [Location of surveillance towers for fire detection and control](https://courseware.e-education.psu.edu/downloads/geog884/guth_others_2005_asprs_conf.pdf);

Guth, P. et al (2005). Fire location from a single Osborne firefinder and a DEM. ASPRS Annual Conference. Baltimore, Maryland.

2- Location of roads,bridges,culverts and construction of terraces aiming to avoid erosion;

3- [Crop transportation](http://www.jeb.co.in/journal_issues/201001_jan10/paper_28.pdf) (both harvest/yarding and main transportation);

Gumus, S., & Acar, H. H. (2009). Evaluation of consecutive skylines yarding and gravity skidding systems in primary forest transportation on steep terrain. Journal of Environmental Biology, 31, 213-218.

4- [Cultivation planning](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/EI143.1) (such as soil preparation, fertilization, weed control) aiming to verify if it is possible to mechanize activities;

Jasinski, E. et al (2005). Physical Landscape Correlates of the Expansion of Mechanized Agriculture in Mato Grosso, Brazil. Earth interactions, 9, 1-18.

5- [Location/Preservation of forest remnants](http://www.fs.fed.us/global/iitf/pubs/ja_iitf_2008_sesnie001.pdf) (e.g. flat areas are more suitable for agriculture than "slopy" areas);

Sesnie, S. E., Hagell, S. E., Otterstrom, S. M., Chambers, C. L., & Dickson, B. G. (2008). SRTM-DEM and Landsat ETM + data for mapping tropical dry forest cover and biodiversity assessment in Nicaragua. Revista Geográfica Acadêmica, 2(2), 53–65.

6- [Soil sampling regarding soil classification](http://hotsites.cnps.embrapa.br/blogs/emdia/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/Ondigitalsoilmapping.pdf) (first time planning and cultivating an area);

McBratney, A. ., Mendonça Santos, M. ., & Minasny, B. (2003). On digital soil mapping. Geoderma, 117(1-2), 3–52. doi:10.1016/S0016-7061(03)00223-4

7- [Appraisal of agricultural lands](http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXVII/congress/2_pdf/5_WG-II-5/08.pdf);

Sakai, T., & Chikatsu, H. (2008). Visualization of road slope aspect for fixed property appraisal of lands using DEM. In ISPRS Commission II, WG II /5 (Vol. XXXVII, pp. 655–658). Beijing.

Answer (score 6):

1. [match soil type with slope and get runoff](http://naldc.nal.usda.gov/download/21088/PDF),
2. [using watersheds with dem and river profile to get flood zones](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/drupal6/files/geog594/examples/Lesson_4_RickEberts.pdf),
3. [slope analysis for crop placement](http://soilproductivity.nres.uiuc.edu/Bulletin811ALL.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Note: I do not working in the agricultural domain, so these are thoughts based on what I would use a DEM for if I were doing large scale planting in a non-commercial way.

**Crop siting:**  If I have a DEM I can derive the slope and aspect of each pixel in relation to the adjacent pixels.  From this I can estimate the potential difficulty in planting and water runoff (slope) as well as the quantity of sunlight I might expect(aspect).